# Missing some of the applications while updating existing apps in my galaxy s3

Tags: applications, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3

While updating the existing applications like *Google maps*, *Play Music* etc from the play store in my Galaxy S3, some applications like *Navigation* & 2 more disappeared from my phone. why is this happened? What can I do to restore them?

Answer (score 2):

Google maps new version is all rounder application for your navigation and maps, You can find that feature inside your new google map application itself, That's the reason why your applications has been some applications are replaced with brand new application which offer all features of replaced applications.

Comment: The "2 more" most likely include *Latitude*, which was removed from Maps and instead (partly) integrated with *Google+* now

Comment: What exactly you are trying to say BIT?

Answer (score 0):

As updating some app will lead to temporary removal of apps from the Application Drawer . So you can simply Reset Your Phone by pressing power button for 5 seconds . It will reload all the states of your Phone. Just Try it
IT WORKED FOR ME EVERYTIME